# Method for selecting multiple dependent data fields in pivot table (for concatenating then exporting)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I've been trying to create a form where employees can select their skills and certifications (i.e. department, category, skill and level) from a pivot table list, and then concatenate and export this data to a .csv file.

[image]

I've already managed to do this using dependent drop down lists (data validation and macros) but it doesn't look as clean as an expandable pivot table and it also only allows for a small/finite amount of skills and certifications to be selected in each row. I'm looking for a pivot table version of this where users can expand each relevant field (department-category-skill-level) and tick/select each branch at the end.. and then ultimately merge then export only the selected data to a csv.

Hope this makes sense - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Go ahead and show what you currently have so we can help you improve your existing code.

Comment: @GrantMiller I don't have any code for the pivot table version I'm after. As mentioned I have a fully functioning version based on dependent drop down lists (data validation + macros) but a pivot table version is fundamentally different - I suppose I am ultimately asking if anyone knows how to add a selection method at the end of a pivot table branch (such as a tickbox)?

Comment: I think pivot tables are the wrong tool for selecting something. I think what you are looking for is something like the [Treeview Control](https://www.homeandlearn.org/introduction_to_treeviews.html).